# PHP and MYSQL check if column value is equal to any value inside array?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have the following query which, theoretically, should gather all entrees in a table with a column value equal to any one of the values inside of the array. Here is my code:

```
$currentname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `entree` WHERE `user` IN(".implode(',',$AllFollows).") AND (`type` == '0' OR `type` == '1') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, $endtime;");
```

There is only one problem with it, it does not work and I have absolutely now idea why. Can someone please tell me what I have done wrong that causes it to disfunction is the expected manner?

Comment: The content of $AllFollow  is type string or number ?

Comment: @scaisEdge its a int

Comment: what's the value for `$AllFollows` and `$endtime`? and where/how are they coming from? are you also successfully connecting with `mysql_` and not another API?

Comment: @Fred-ii- $allFollows = 1,2,5,8 but it changes often. and endtime = 5

Comment: @user7133318 reload the answer below, there were a few edits made to it, some of which I fixed. Check for errors on the query with `mysql_error()` as well as using error reporting. If there are any, let them know. You may also like to post your db schema and values for it.

Answer (score 1):

Your IN  content is not formed  correctly ( you pass a value inside double quete not a list of value ) ..try

```
  $my_in_value  =  "";
  foreach ($AllFollows as $key => $value) {
      if ($my_in_value == "" ) {
        $my_in_value =  $value;
      } else{
        $my_in_value = $my_in_value. ", ". $value . " ";
      }    
  }


  $currentname = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                        FROM `entree` 
                        WHERE `user` IN (" . $my_in_value ") 
                        AND (`type` == '0' OR `type` == '1') 
                        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, $endtime;");
```

Comment: @user7133318   . asnwer  updated .. (refuse remove ) and adapted the code for int ..

Comment: @scaisEdge added many missing `;` - maybe the OP might not have spotted that and unsure if that would have been the "clincher".

Comment: however `if $my_in_value = ""` should probably be `if $my_in_value == ""` so you may need to re-edit. @scaisEdge or to `if ($my_in_value == "")` ? also unsure. Only "you" know that ;-)